# Is it possible to boot form M.2 NMVE on old motherboards?

Tags: ssd, adapter

I have ASUS M5A97_R20 AM3+ https://www.asus.com/SupportOnly/M5A97_R20/HelpDesk_Manual/ motherboard. With two PCI-E x16 slots and want to use M.2 NMVE -> PCI-E x16 adapter to attach the disk, is it possible to boot from such disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most motherboards can boot from PCIe based storage, though it's difficult to guarantee it will work on a specific board without trying it.

In reference to you other question, you will not be able to boot from a software Raid. If you want to set up a Raid AND boot from it, you will need to use a hardware raid card like this:  [highpoint card](https://www.highpoint-tech.com/ssd7000-series-overview)
But these are much more expensive than normal adapters.

Typical application is to use a USB drive to boot from and put everything else on a software Raid using the cheaper adapter.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me more about boot from software RAID (0,1) how to create it? What I need to do with me USB stick? I need to boot Debian Linus and sometimes Windows 10

Comment: You can't boot from software RAID, so you need another drive to boot from. That other drive can be something as small as a USB. Booting into two different operating systems "dual boot" is a big topic and i suggest you check the main stack exchange if you really want to try it.